# $request->has() doesn't work with Button type and using jQuery in Laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have question on Laravel with jQuery.

Right now, I have form with **three (3)** different buttons (**update,delete,email**). Each button have different task in controller.

Normally I use **button type="submit"** to submit data from blade into controller.

**Blade**

```
<form id='form-info' class="form-info" action="{{url('/form/sendData')}}" method="post">
@csrf  

    <input type="text" id="info" class="info" name="name" value="test"/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" name="update" id="update">Update</button>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" name="delete" id="delete">Delete</button>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" name="email" id="email">Email</button>   
</form>
```

And in controller, I just use '**$request->has()**' to differentiate three request.

```
if ($request->has('update')) 
{
    echo 'update';
} 
else if($request->has('delete'))
{
    echo 'delete';
} 
else if($request->has('email'))
{
    echo 'email';
}
```

But my current goal is to show loading icon before data successfully submitted.

The reason why I want to show loading page is because system need to send an email to multiple user and it might take some time to load before it finished the task. To prevent user to click the same button multiple times.

I use **jQuery click function** and I change button type from '**submit**' to '**button**'.

But the problem is when the form submitted to controller. It doesn't recognize '**$request->has()**' in my controller.

Here's my html form and jQuery and my controller

**blade.php**

```
<form id='form-info' class="form-info" action="{{url('/form/sendData')}}" method="post">
@csrf  

    <input type="text" id="info" class="info" name="name" value="test"/>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" name="update" id="update">Update</button>  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" name="delete" id="delete">Delete</button>  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" name="email" id="email">Email</button>   
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#update').click(function(){ 

        $(".loader").show(); 
        $("#form-info").submit();
        $(".loader").hide();

    });

    $('#delete').click(function(){ 

        $(".loader").show(); 
        $("#form-info").submit();
        $(".loader").hide();

    });

    $('#email').click(function(){ 

        $(".loader").show(); 
        $("#form-info").submit();
        $(".loader").hide();

    });

});
```

**Controller.php**

```
if ($request->has('update')) 
{
    echo 'update';
} 
else if($request->has('delete'))
{
    echo 'delete';
} 
else if($request->has('email'))
{
    echo 'email';
}
```

How to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use CRUD operation, mean separate routes for each actions.

Comment: @parth, different route and different controller ?

Comment: No need for different controller, just routes. More information on [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

Comment: And, also, you should switch to an AJAX call, so it will be easier for you.

Comment: change button to <input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="update" /> will work same for all buttons.